# How to calculate the OLEDB Destination Rowsperbatch and MaximuminsertCommitSize to get maximum Performance

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008, ssis-2005

In SSIS ,If we  select the FAST LOAD Option then we have to set the 2 properties

OLEDB Destination Rowsperbatch and 
    MaximuminsertCommitSize

Normally ,we go with default values ;but it has been understood that it gives a maximum performance if we can calculate these values(Just seen in a package which has been developed by some old collegues ,who already left the team).

How to calculate theses

```
 OLEDB Destination Rowsperbatch and 
    MaximuminsertCommitSize
```

propertiesd value  to get maximum Performance?

Answer (score 1):

There is no set formula for this.  It's basically - understanding the impacts they have, and trial and error (preferably on a dev environment).

If you are inserting large files -- you should not use the defaults, but no one will be able to give a set formula for what you should use.

Every server/database is different.  But large commit sizes can result in huge tempdb growth.. so understanding and caution is needed.

[Here's a good link to Best Practices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2013/09/16/top-10-sql-server-integration-services-best-practices.aspx) from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739320/ssis-2008-rows-per-batch-and-maximum-insert-commit-size).